# Convert Date to UTC from othertimezone [CST CDT]

Tags: javascript

I am working on event planning content setup project
problem is i have user sitting in India will set up content for US[America/Chicago] timezone
for them we have made a date picker which will get a date that time supposed to be Always America/Chicago time . for that, I am retrieving date like : 12/31/2020 11:45pm [MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm A] now this time i want to convert in UTC

> the challenge here is: since the user is in India there time zone will
>   come in date is IST but I wanted to get timezone from either CST or
>   CDT . how to determine which timezone is in [America/Chicago] for date
>   12/31/2020 11:45pm

Comment: You can use moment library for this conversion , also please your code so that we can help you better.

Comment: While saving date send it in UTC from frontend.
And while displaying you get the date in UTC from server and just add client offset from UTC.

Comment: @ricky but here challenge is user is in india and they will set content of america hence assuming amrica zone time only